# Understanding Scala MiMa Output

Tags: scala, binary-compatibility

I'm attempting to use MiMa(https://github.com/lightbend/migration-manager#usage) to determine any binary incompatibilities between argonaut-shapeless's v1.2.0-M9 and v1.2.0-M6. Please see the output, where I post what I did, as well as ask my question.

```
# clone argonaut-shapeless
# cd to directory
$git branch
* (HEAD detached at v1.2.0-M9)
  master
$git diff
diff --git a/build.sbt b/build.sbt
index 6465b3c..e1e5ac4 100644
--- a/build.sbt
+++ b/build.sbt
@@ -104,6 +104,7 @@ lazy val `argonaut-shapeless` = project
   )
   .settings(
     shared,
+    mimaPreviousArtifacts := Set("com.github.alexarchambault" %%% "argonaut-shapeless_6.2" % "1.2.0-M6"),
     dontPublish
   )

diff --git a/project/plugins.sbt b/project/plugins.sbt
index 0f055fc..490c9de 100644
--- a/project/plugins.sbt
+++ b/project/plugins.sbt
@@ -6,4 +6,7 @@ addSbtPlugin("org.scala-native" % "sbt-scala-native" % "0.3.8")
 addSbtPlugin("org.portable-scala" % "sbt-scalajs-crossproject" % "0.5.0")
 addSbtPlugin("org.portable-scala" % "sbt-scala-native-crossproject" % "0.5.0")

+addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe" % "sbt-mima-plugin" % "0.3.0")
+
+
 addSbtCoursier
```

Next, run MIMA to determine any binary incompatibilities:

```
sbt:argonaut-shapeless> mimaReportBinaryIssues
[info] Updating argonaut-shapeless
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.12/scala-library-2.11.12.pom
  100.0% [##########] 1.4 KiB (3.0 KiB / s)
[info] Resolved argonaut-shapeless dependencies
[info] Updating argonaut-shapeless
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalamacros/paradise_2.11.12/2.1.1/paradise_2.11.12-2.1.1.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.0 KiB (18.3 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.12/scala-compiler-2.11.12.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.3 KiB (22.5 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.12/scala-reflect-2.11.12.pom
  100.0% [##########] 1.5 KiB (5.8 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.11/1.0.4/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.1 KiB (20.4 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.0.5/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.5.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.5 KiB (23.9 KiB / s)
[info] Resolved argonaut-shapeless dependencies
[info] Updating argonaut-shapeless
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.14.3/jline-2.14.3.pom
  100.0% [##########] 19.4 KiB (99.1 KiB / s)
[info] Resolved argonaut-shapeless dependencies
[info] Updating refined
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/chuusai/shapeless_2.11/2.3.3/shapeless_2.11-2.3.3.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.2 KiB (21.6 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/eu/timepit/refined_2.11/0.9.2/refined_2.11-0.9.2.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.8 KiB (20.5 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/argonaut/argonaut_2.11/6.2.2/argonaut_2.11-6.2.2.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.4 KiB (8.4 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/typelevel/macro-compat_2.11/1.1.1/macro-compat_2.11-1.1.1.pom
  100.0% [##########] 1.9 KiB (19.5 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.1.0/scala-xml_2.11-1.1.0.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.7 KiB (24.0 KiB / s)
[info] Resolved refined dependencies
[info] Updating coreJS
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-js/scalajs-library_2.11/0.6.26/scalajs-library_2.11-0.6.26.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.2 KiB (15.9 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/argonaut/argonaut_sjs0.6_2.11/6.2.2/argonaut_sjs0.6_2.11-6.2.2.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.8 KiB (12.7 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-js/scalajs-test-interface_2.11/0.6.26/scalajs-test-interface_2.11-0.6.26.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.2 KiB (14.6 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/chuusai/shapeless_sjs0.6_2.11/2.3.3/shapeless_sjs0.6_2.11-2.3.3.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.7 KiB (8.9 KiB / s)
[info] Resolved coreJS dependencies
[info] Updating coreJS
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-js/scalajs-compiler_2.11.12/0.6.26/scalajs-compiler_2.11.12-0.6.26.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.6 KiB (20.7 KiB / s)
[info] Resolved coreJS dependencies
[info] Updating coreTestJS
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lihaoyi/utest_sjs0.6_2.11/0.6.6/utest_sjs0.6_2.11-0.6.6.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.2 KiB (15.3 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless_1.13_sjs0.6_2.11/1.1.8/scalacheck-shapeless_1.13_sjs0.6_2.11-1.1.8.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.5 KiB (13.3 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/portable-scala/portable-scala-reflect_sjs0.6_2.11/0.1.0/portable-scala-reflect_sjs0.6_2.11-0.1.0.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.6 KiB (19.5 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalacheck/scalacheck_sjs0.6_2.11/1.13.5/scalacheck_sjs0.6_2.11-1.13.5.pom
  100.0% [##########] 1.8 KiB (13.0 KiB / s)
[info] Resolved coreTestJS dependencies
[info] Fetching artifacts of coreJS
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/typelevel/macro-compat_2.11/1.1.1/macro-compat_2.11-1.1.1.jar
  100.0% [##########] 3.1 KiB (27.9 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalamacros/paradise_2.11.12/2.1.1/paradise_2.11.12-2.1.1.jar
  100.0% [##########] 265.2 KiB (541.2 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-js/scalajs-test-interface_2.11/0.6.26/scalajs-test-interface_2.11-0.6.26.jar
  100.0% [##########] 485.6 KiB (552.4 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.0.5/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.5.jar
  100.0% [##########] 655.4 KiB (1.1 MiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/chuusai/shapeless_sjs0.6_2.11/2.3.3/shapeless_sjs0.6_2.11-2.3.3.jar
  100.0% [##########] 6.8 MiB (4.3 MiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.12/scala-library-2.11.12.jar
  100.0% [##########] 5.5 MiB (5.0 MiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.14.3/jline-2.14.3.jar
  100.0% [##########] 262.2 KiB (2.2 MiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.11/1.0.4/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar
  100.0% [##########] 413.8 KiB (2.1 MiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-js/scalajs-compiler_2.11.12/0.6.26/scalajs-compiler_2.11.12-0.6.26.jar
  100.0% [##########] 1.8 MiB (566.5 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/argonaut/argonaut_sjs0.6_2.11/6.2.2/argonaut_sjs0.6_2.11-6.2.2.jar
  100.0% [##########] 3.4 MiB (630.7 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.12/scala-compiler-2.11.12.jar
  100.0% [##########] 14.9 MiB (2.6 MiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.12/scala-reflect-2.11.12.jar
  100.0% [##########] 4.4 MiB (464.2 KiB / s)
[info] Fetched artifacts of coreJS
[info] Fetching artifacts of refined
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.1.0/scala-xml_2.11-1.1.0.jar
  100.0% [##########] 656.1 KiB (1.5 MiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/eu/timepit/refined_2.11/0.9.2/refined_2.11-0.9.2.jar
  100.0% [##########] 618.0 KiB (771.6 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/argonaut/argonaut_2.11/6.2.2/argonaut_2.11-6.2.2.jar
  100.0% [##########] 2.0 MiB (1.7 MiB / s)
[info] Fetched artifacts of refined
[info] Fetching artifacts of coreTestJS
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/kmeredith/Workspace/argonaut-shapeless/refined/target/scala-2.11/classes ...ess_1.13_sjs0.6_2.11-1.1.8.jar
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources to /Users/kmeredith/Workspace/argonaut-shapeless/core/js/target/scala-2.11/classes ...ess_1.13_sjs0.6_2.11-1.1.8.jar
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/portable-scala/portable-scala-reflect_sjs0.6_2.11/0.1.0/portable-scala-reflect_sjs0.6_2.11-0.1.0.jar
  100.0% [##########] 6.6 KiB (32.0 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless_1.13_sjs0.6_2.11/1.1.8/scalacheck-shapeless_1.13_sjs0.6_2.11-1.1.8.jar
  100.0% [##########] 334.4 KiB (1.0 MiB / s)
[info] Non-compiled module 'compiler-bridge_2.11' for Scala 2.11.12. Compiling...check_sjs0.6_2.11-1.13.5.jar
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lihaoyi/utest_sjs0.6_2.11/0.6.6/utest_sjs0.6_2.11-0.6.6.jar
  100.0% [##########] 706.7 KiB (1.3 MiB / s)
[info] Fetched artifacts of coreTestJS
http://dl.bintray.com/tpolecat/maven/org/tpolecat/tut-core_2.11/0.6.3/tut-core_2.11-0.6.3.pom
  100.0% [##########] 1.8 KiB (2.4 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.0.6/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.6.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.5 KiB (19.5 KiB / s)
[info] Resolved doc dependencies
[info] Updating coreTestJVMen2/com/github/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless_1.13_2.11/1.1.8/scalacheck-shapeless_1.13_2.11-1.1.8.pom
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless_1.13_2.11/1.1.8/scalacheck-shapeless_1.13_2.11-1.1.8.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.1 KiB (22.0 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lihaoyi/utest_2.11/0.6.6/utest_2.11-0.6.6.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.3 KiB (10.9 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalacheck/scalacheck_2.11/1.13.5/scalacheck_2.11-1.13.5.pom
  100.0% [##########] 1.6 KiB (13.2 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/portable-scala/portable-scala-reflect_2.11/0.1.0/portable-scala-reflect_2.11-0.1.0.pom
  100.0% [##########] 2.4 KiB (17.7 KiB / s)
[info] Resolved coreTestJVM dependencies
[info] Fetching artifacts of coreTestJVM
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/portable-scala/portable-scala-reflect_2.11/0.1.0/portable-scala-reflect_2.11-0.1.0.jar
  100.0% [##########] 33.7 KiB (234.1 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless_1.13_2.11/1.1.8/scalacheck-shapeless_1.13_2.11-1.1.8.jar
  100.0% [##########] 207.7 KiB (865.6 KiB / s)
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lihaoyi/utest_2.11/0.6.6/utest_2.11-0.6.6.jar
  100.0% [##########] 427.9 KiB (1.0 MiB / s)
[info] Fetched artifacts of coreTestJVM
[info] Fetching artifacts of docaven/org/tpolecat/tut-core_2.11/0.6.3/tut-core_2.11-0.6.3.jar
[info] Fetched artifacts of doc
not a directory or jar file: /Users/kmeredith/Workspace/argonaut-shapeless/target/scala-2.11/classes
2019-03-04 09:50:30,503 pool-28-thread-2 ERROR No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources to /Users/kmeredith/Workspace/argonaut-shapeless/core/jvm/target/scala-2.11/classes ...
$
```

So there's no binary incompatibilities per this lack of output?

Comment: introduce a binary incompatibility and see if it gets caught by what you're doing